# Different between command .expandX() and .expand() in table

Tags: android, libgdx

I create my project libGDX and import it in Android studio. When I create a table and add Label, I could use .expandX() or .expand(). Look my follower code to understund.

```
Label Label1;
Label Label2;

Table table = new Table();
table.top();
table.setFillParent(true);
Label1 = new Label("I'am", new Label.LabelStyle(new BitmapFont(), Color.WHITE));
Label2 = new Label("Ian", new Label.LabelStyle(new BitmapFont(), Color.WHITE));
table.add(levelLabel).expandX();
table.add(countdownLabel).expand();
```

Which one should I use? and why? What are the differences?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`expand()` is a combination of `expandX()` and `expandY()`. So if you want to allow expanding in height (if there is room for this) expand() would allow that.

Which you should use depends entirely on the result you want!

as a sidenote:
Use `expand()` to make the logical cell expand within the table. if more than 1 cells have the expand tag, they will both expend using their sizes for ratio. If you want both to have the same size add 'uniform'
use `fill()` to expand the actor inside the cell to fill the the logical cell.
Use `grow()` to combine both of them in 1 command.
They all have the X and Y variants to only work in 1 direction.